# CSS Menu Disappears after mouse hover

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have a little issue with a menu on my Joomla 2.5 page. It's a module and I used several CSS properties like:

```
visibility:visible; z-index:99999!important
```

Yet, the menu does not delays for me to click it.

I want the menu to be clickable when the reader mouse over and mouse on the second level menu. I don't want it to disappear any more.

A sample of what I want the menu to look like can be found here: http://vitafoam.com.ng

Answer (score 0):

On the css class `ul.navi ul.level2` on menustyle.css, remove the `top: 91px` property. It is throwing your level2 menu down, and keeping you from hovering it.

Removing the `top` property fixed the problem, at least on my Chrome Debug.

Comment: No, thats not my question, i really want that menu to be there, right now, i have removed the top:91px and it has taken it back up. what i want is this: the menu will be on those images and clickable.. just like this site's menu: http://vitafoam.com.ng/ i want to replicate something like this. is this achievable??

Comment: When you look at the menu, it's being displaced some inches away. that is what i wanna replicate. how do i go about it? or better still, can someone delay the seconds in which the submenu disappears?